# Updated Magento php files not appearing to show changes

Tags: php, magento

Forgive me if this is a silly question, I'm new to Magento development.

I'm trying to replicate an issue one of our clients is having and to do this I've got to change a php file to the same as his.

The problem is I've changed the file but the expected outcome is not happening. Am I required to do something before the changes .php files are used or should they be updated the second they're uploaded to the server?

Comment: You're skipping a lot of necessary information...what are the PHP files? Are they Magento blocks? If so, you'll probably need to clear the cache. Are they rewrites of core classes? If so, you might be missing some necessary config XML.

Comment: What is the file name that you are trying to change? File path ?

Answer (score 2):

When doing Magento development, always turn off caching so you get immediate changes shown.

HTML blocks cache will keep your template and block changes from showing until the cached block is refreshed.

Layout cache will keep changes in layouts xml from showing until the cached layout is refreshed.

Configuration cache will keep changes in core_config_data from showing until the cached config is refreshed.

Front page cache will cache the whole page and prevent seeing changes till the page cache is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

If your change is not reflected than probably that is not the file magento is using. In which file you are trying to change? If you are changing the file that lies inside

> app/code/core

or

> app/design.frontend/base

Than those files may have been overriden in your local folder(For .php files) or in your theme folder(For .phtml files).

One method of knowing which file magento is currently using to enable the **template path hint**. This can give you the exact location of the phtml files but not the php files.But it will help you to trace it.

Hope this will help.